# Big-O of Set of Functions

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm a bit puzzled on how to understand a bound.

We have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that

$$ f(n) = n^2 - n + 2 $$

and

$$ g(n) = 4n^2 +3n +2 $$

If we try to see if $f = O(g)$, we use the limit definition:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 - n + 2}{4n^2 + 3n + 2} $$
$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n -1}{8n + 2} $$
$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac28 = \frac14 $$

Where, when graphed, $\frac14 (g)$ is an upper bound of $f$.

When we try to see if $f = \Omega(g)$, this is the result:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^2 + 3n + 2}{n^2 - n + 2} $$
$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac41 = 4 $$

When graphed, $4(g)$ is not a lower bound of $f$. By the definition of big-$\Omega$, $f(n) \geq c \cdot g(n)$ for some $c \geq 0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = c $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last statement about $c$ is false. For your specific case you can pick $c = \frac14 - \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ to make the inequality work. It may be helpful to notice that any polynomial of degree at most $k$ is in $O(n^k)$ and any polynomial of degree at least $k$ is in $\Omega(n^k)$.

It could also help to settle the definitions of $O$ and $\Omega$:

$$f\in O(g) :\Leftrightarrow \exists C>0, N\in\mathbb N \text{ s.t. } \forall n\ge N: f(n) \le C\cdot g(n)\\
f\in \Omega(g) :\Leftrightarrow \exists c>0, N\in\mathbb N \text{ s.t. } \forall n\ge N: f(n) \ge c\cdot g(n)$$

So you always have the existence of some constant such that eventually $f$ will be bounded above (resp. below) by $c\cdot g$.

Comment: So $c \geq \epsilon \geq 0$ because $c \geq 0$? In short, $\epsilon$ has to be between the value of the limit and 0, as $c$ cannot be negative, correct?

Comment: @apizzimenti $c$ must be _positive_. $c = 0$ is not valid. Else you could show $x \in \Omega(x^2)$ read "$x$ grows at least as fast as $x^2$", wich is obviously not true. You must chose $c$ in between $0$ and the "value of the limit", excluding both ends. But the actual choice of $c$ (and $N$) is irrelevant to the result.

Comment: So $c > \epsilon > 0$ and $c = C - \epsilon$ in this case? Or is that a general rule?

Comment: @apizzimenti No no, forget about that $\epsilon$. It only means chose $\frac14 > c > 0$. For $C$ you will usually have to chose it larger than the limit, but in this case $C = \frac14$ works because the low-order terms are such that they don't need an extra $\varepsilon x^2$ to be dominated. If you call the limit $L = \lim \frac fg$, all you will always be able to say is that $C \ge L \ge c > 0$ must hold.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood. I took the $\epsilon$ to indicate that there is a difference between $C$ and $c$, as a function cannot be both bounded above and below by the same function.


For clarification, if $C \leq L \leq c$, then $C \leq c$. However, there has to be some difference between $C$ and $c$, as $C \cdot g$ and $c \cdot g$ can't exist as upper and lower bounds of $f$ if they have the same value. Is this a reasonable assumption? 

PS, sorry for getting more in-depth. I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: @apizzimenti No. $C$ and $c$ can sometimes be the same. Consider $f=g$. Then $C=c=1$ is always possible.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my question to say that it was for functions that were not equal or whose limit was not 1. In any case, thank you for answering all of this, sorry it got so long. Much appreciated!